# Form multiple rows from one original row for group of columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

To achieve what I want (see the attached screen shot #2 below), my current solution is I am using UNION ALL. However, with that solution, SQL scripts are repeated with multiple SELECT and UNION ALL statements.

**My question**: is there a better and simpler solution to avoid script repetition.

Details of my assignment:

I have a variable table that holds all student Courses per row as follows:

[image]

What I want is to use another variable table that holds only ONE Course per row as follows:

[image]

My current solution is using UNION ALL but I have to repeat SQL scripts:

```
declare @t table(StudentFirstName nvarchar(50), StudentLastName nvarchar(50), Course1 nvarchar(50), Course2 nvarchar(50), Course3 nvarchar(50), Course4 nvarchar(50), Course5 nvarchar(50))
declare @t2 table(StudentFirstName nvarchar(50), StudentLastName nvarchar(50), Course nvarchar(50))

insert @t
select 'Adam', 'Smith', 'A', 'B', 'C', null, null
union all
select 'Bob', 'Kenneth', null, 'Y', 'X', 'E', null
union all
select 'Yath', 'McConnel', null, 'H', null, null, null

---- check
select * from @t


insert @t2
(
    StudentFirstName 
    , StudentLastName  
    , Course 
)
select 
StudentFirstName
, StudentLastName
, Course1
from @t

union all

select 
StudentFirstName
, StudentLastName
, Course2
from @t

union all

select 
StudentFirstName
, StudentLastName
, Course3
from @t

union all

select 
StudentFirstName
, StudentLastName
, Course4
from @t

union all
select 
StudentFirstName
, StudentLastName
, Course5
from @t

-- check
select * from @t2 
order by StudentFirstName, StudentLastName
```

Comment: you can try [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#unpivot-example)

Answer (score 1):

As per Dordi's suggestion, UNPIVOT will do the job:

```
declare @t table(StudentFirstName nvarchar(50), StudentLastName nvarchar(50), Course1 nvarchar(50), Course2 nvarchar(50), Course3 nvarchar(50), Course4 nvarchar(50), Course5 nvarchar(50))

insert @t
select 'Adam', 'Smith', 'A', 'B', 'C', null, null
union all
select 'Bob', 'Kenneth', null, 'Y', 'X', 'E', null
union all
select 'Yath', 'McConnel', null, 'H', null, null, null

select  StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, c.Course
from @t
unpivot (Course for CourseField in (Course1, Course2, Course3, Course4, Course5)) c
```